# Regarding a simple installer for COM dlls

Tags: windows, com, wix, installation

i have been using Installshiled for installing this SDK, but this is giving us lot of troubles sometimes with users accounts etc...but my SDK has few com components and few regular dlls and help files.

my tasks are very few and i don't think i need to use this costly software
Installation:
1)copy the dlls into a specific folder
2)register the COM dlls
3)Add few registry entries
4)copy help files

uninstall:
1) unregister all COM dlls
2) delete all dlls including regular dlls
3) remove registry entries
4) delete help files

can anyone suggest any free installer where i can do the above things easily

Comment: From the tags you assigned, it seems you already know about [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/). Does it not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: but there is a learning curve for that and it is not easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pretty routine stuff - all installers do this basic stuff. If it's WiX (which is free), use Heat to extract the registration, install the files, and the rest just works. Your question is too broad to answer, so here's the WiX tutorial.

http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/

Installs are generally more complicated and more work than people expect.

Apart from WiX maybe the Visual Studio you use will have either InstallShield LE or the new VS 2012/2013 installer extension.

Comment: If you don't want to use the WiX approach you can try to use a free edition of a tool for creating installation packages. I use [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) which is an easy to use tool with a very intuitive UI.